# How do I append a new row to the body of a table in HTML using a javascript function that acts on a checkbox click?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been using the following resources:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp
- https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-dom-exercise-5.php

And my HTML code with the javascript function is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<h1>Checkbox Test</h1>
</head>
    <body>
        <table class="tb" id="checky">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Checkbox 1</th>
                <th>Checkbox 2</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="Team1_checkbox" id="1" onchange="doalert(this)"  /> &nbsp; </td> 
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="Team2_checkbox" id="2" onchange="doalert(this)" /> &nbsp; </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script>
            function doalert(checkboxElem) {
              if (checkboxElem.checked) {
              
            var table=document.getElementByID("checky");
            var row=table.insertRow(0);
            
            alert("checked");
            
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

            cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
            cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";

              } else {
                alert("notchecked");
              }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The checkbox when checked does nothing but when unchecked it does display the alert, so I'm not quite sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, function names are case sensitive.
You have bug in line:

```
 var table=document.getElementByID("checky");
```

Should be:

```
 var table=document.getElementById("checky");
```

Change function name `getElementByID` -> `getElementById`.

Correct this small bug and everything will work.

Comment: Amazing! I thought it was something simple but missed that small detail. I've changed my code and it now runs!

Comment: Try to use DevTools in your browser. The error was clearly communicated.

Comment: Ahh okay, I'm new to javascript and html so I was only vaguely aware that DevTools is a thing. It appears when you right click navigate to Inspect and will be part of the pane that appears.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is trying to return. `this` returning only `this` will return the input element and that is not what you want to get, what you want to return is `this.checked` which will return `true` or `false` depending on the if the checkbox is checked or not

I have rewritten your find the changes below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <h1>Checkbox Test</h1>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="tb" id="checky">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Checkbox 1</th>
                <th>Checkbox 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="Team1_checkbox" id="1" onchange="doalert(this.checked)" /> &nbsp; </td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="Team2_checkbox" id="2" onchange="doalert(this.checked)" /> &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        function doalert(checkboxElem) {

            // console.log(checkboxElem);
            if (checkboxElem) {
              //correct the getElementByID
                var table = document.getElementById("checky");
                var row = table.insertRow(0);

                alert("checked");

                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

                cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
                cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";

            } else {
                alert("notchecked");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```